# Why is ffmpeg-python not able to find my files?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Using Python 3.7.7 with ffmpeg-python 0.2.0 on Windows 10 64-bit.

This is my main .py file:

```
import ffmpeg
input_video = ffmpeg.input('./Output/temp_video.mp4')
input_audio = ffmpeg.input('./Output/temp_audio.mp4')
ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output('./Output/finished_video.mp4').run()
```

When I run it I get this error even though all the files mentioned are in the specified folder.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHDuv.png)